How can I measure the start time with the Flutter App when opening
I just want to find out how can I get the app start up time the moment it opens, I tried using DevTools for that but I get other factors like slow time, framers per seconds and all that but could not find app start up time. Can you please assist in how can I do that using DevTools or with the code please.

You can use Splash Screen with Future(Duration)
